# Azure web app instance memory usage, high page reads/sec?

Tags: azure, memory, azure-web-app-service, ddos

I have a medium Azure instance (PaaS) with 9 apps. The apps have not changed for some time.
Yet, for the last three days, I'm getting warnings about high memory usage. Interestingly, the combined memory usage of my apps is steady, it doesn't really change. The memory usage of the whole instance hikes. As you can see, in the last day, it even made the whole instance crash multiple times.

[image: Memory usage]

There is a pattern in the **page reads/second** which is worrying, and seems to correlate with memory usage hikes. Could it be a sign of (D)DoS attack? As far as I know, Azure detects those attacks.

[image: page reads/second]

What may cause the hikes?

Comment: Are the peaks exactly spaced or sort of random? And is the time pattern predictable? Hard to say from above, but might be able to tell by zooming in. Note that realistically, you might need a support case for this one.